# Left join and belongs to

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, belongs-to

I have three tables: *products* (id, name), *categories* (id, name) and *products_categories* (product_id, category_id).

Each *product* belongs to one or more categories.

I want to retrieve all products, and show which ones are already in category "X".
My divs are like this:

```
   <span>Category "X"</span>
   [some php / fetch_assoc() / … ]
   <div class="product">Product A</div>
   <div class="product selected">Product B</div>
   <div class="product">Product B</div>
```

For now, it work with two queries: one to fetch all the products, and one to check if the product is in products_categories. So it's a lot of small queries with php inside the first one.

```
$getAllProducts = "SELECT products.name as productName, products.id as productID FROM products";
$resultProduct=$mysqli->query($getAllProducts);
while($product=$resultProduct->fetch_assoc()){
    $reqChecked = "SELECT * FROM products_categories
                   WHERE product_id=" .  $product["productID"] ."
                   AND category_id=" . $category["id"]; //$category["id"] is given
    $resultChecked = $mysqli->query($reqChecked);
    $row = $resultChecked->fetch_row();
    $selected = ""
    if ( isset($row[0]) ) {
        $selected = "selected";
    }
```

**It is possible to do it with only one query?** I tried with a *left join* (products_categories on products), but the products belonging to multiple categories are listed for every categories they're in.

**EDIT**

Here is some sample data

**Product table**

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | product_1 |
|  2 | product_2 |
|  3 | product_3 |
+----+-----------+
```

**category table**

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | category_1 |
|  2 | category_2 |
|  3 | category_3 |
+----+------------+
```

**joining table**

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           1 |
|          1 |           2 |
|          2 |           2 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Now, let's say I'm on a page editing category_2, and I want the following result:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| product_id | product_name | category_id |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
|          1 | product_1    | 2           | --product_1 belongs to category_1 and category_2, but I only need it one time.
|          2 | product_2    | 2           |
|          3 | product_3    | NULL        | --product_3 belongs to nothing but I want to see it.
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your existing queries?

Comment: I just added my (ugly) queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a simple join problem.  I originally thought you might need some query magic to show whether a product belongs to a given category.  But if you just use the query below, you can check the category name for each row in your PHP and act accordingly.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name AS product,
       c.name AS category       -- check for value 'X' in your PHP code
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_categories pc
    ON p.id = pc.product_id
INNER JOIN categories c
    ON c.id = pc.category_id
```

Note that your current approach is actually trying to do the join in the PHP code itself, which is undesirable for so many reasons.

**Update:**

```
SELECT t1.id AS product_id,
       t1.name AS product_name,
       CASE WHEN t2.productSum > 0 THEN '2' ELSE 'NA' END AS category_id
FROM products t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id,
           SUM(CASE WHEN category_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS productSum
    FROM products_categories
    GROUP BY product_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.product_id
```

Comment: After a few tests, it does not work as I want. If a product doesn't belongs to any category, it won't show - solved with **LEFT JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN**.Now, if a products belongs to two categories, both *products* will show, and I want only one. In short, I want all products on the left, and on the right a way to tell if the product belong to category 'X.id'.

Comment: @shlagwuk Please show sample data so that this is clear.

Comment: I've added sample data to my first post.

Comment: Your edit is unclear.  What does `product_2` have `category_id` 2 next to it?

Comment: Because both `product_1` and `product_2` belongs to `category_2`. It's OK with your update, thanks a lot!